# Authorization in the application deploying on the Heroku using JWT Token

Tags: node.js, heroku, authorization, jwt

After completing the back-end part and testing of the application, I tried to run it on the Heroku server. Locally registration and receipt of all messages work.
[My App Warbler](https://warbler-client-react.herokuapp.com/)
On the Heroku server, only registration is working, after successful registration Token is sent to the client. To receive messages, the client adds a Token to the request body.
The server replies that I am not authorized:

```
2019-09-24T08:22:02.047721+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/api/messages" host=warbler-server-md.herokuapp.com request_id=849b48c9-caa9-4e7c-b38c-b614988b88e4 fwd="178.159.232.145,3.88.204.168" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=2ms status=401 bytes=293 protocol=https
```

The most likely problem is Token authentication:

```js
exports.ensureCorrectUser = function(req, res, next) {
    try {
        const token = req.headers.authorization.split(' ')[1];
        jwt.verify(token, process.env.SECRET_KEY, function(err, decoded) {
            console.log("token", token);
            console.log("decoded", decoded);
            if (decoded && decoded.id === req.params.id) {
                return next();
            } else {
                console.log(err);
                return next({
                    status: 401,
                    message: 'Unauthorized'
                });
            }
        });
    } catch (error) {
        console.log('Unauthorized!');
        next({
            status: 401,
            message: 'Unauthorized'
        });
    }
};
```

It seems to me that this code does not start at all since the messages that I added are not displayed in the console.

What's wrong with authorization?

Comment: do you have the `process.env.SECRET_KEY` variable set on heroku?

Comment: Yes:
=== warbler-server-md Config Vars
SECRET_KEY:  fhudaskjfhajskldhfri3hf3829cah9fhjdkhdskjfhsk